# writing os.system output to file

Tags: python, coding-style

basically, I want to output the os.system results to a file based on sys.argv input. See below for the code. It throws me the error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. My guess is that the output operator > does not accept variables?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
nfile = sys.argv[1]
intfile=('/folder/folder/%s/%s.txt' % (nfile, nfile)) 

if os.path.isfile(intfile): # if file exist remove
    os.remove(intfile)
else: 
    os.system('sudo ovs-vsctl list-ports %s > %s' % (nfile, intfile)
```

Comment: `os.system('sudo ovs-vsctl list-ports %s > %s' % (nswitch, intfile))`, missed the closing `)`. Use `subprocess.call` instead of `os.system`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a single character typo.


Answer (score 2):

`os.system` is frowned upon. The `subprocess` module is cleaner, safer and as powerful as `os.system()`.

```
import subprocess
with open(intfile, 'w') as outfile:
    subprocess.call(['sudo', 'ovs-vsctl', 'list-ports', nfile], stdout=outfile)
```